# Is Creatine related to hair loss?

Tags: health, supplements, creatine

I have heard comments from body builders that Creatine increases the chances of hair loss. I have heard comments from other body builders that it does not. But these are mostly anecdotal and unsubstantiated.

Has a there been any scientific evidence to conclude whether creatine does or does not increase the chance of hair loss?

Comment: Several videos on YouTube about this exact topic. To sum them up no, it does not cause hair loss. Don’t over do it for long periods of time because there are other side affects. Other than that 5g a day, everyday, workouts or not, it is beneficial.

Comment: Greg Nuckolz discusses this for over an hour on [this episode](https://open.spotify.com/episode/5mBS7XdCVRVSuh5Z67hfJL?si=CBAX4WagQhmUwTSzPNeWaQ) of the stronger by science podcast.

Answer (score -1):

Some folks claim creatine might up your hair loss chances, but others disagree. There are studies pointing to creatine boosting dihydrotestosterone (DHT), a hormone tied to hair loss. Yet, other studies don't back this up. If hair loss worries you, play it safe and consult with your doctor